# How to suppress space between two HTML elements

Tags: html

I need to supress the space between $ and amount
Now it is showing $ 23   it should show $23

```
 <span style="color: Red;white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px">$
                                                <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:F}", item.cy_list_price))%></span>
```

Comment: Why are you showing you .NET server code? This is a brower-side issue.

Comment: Why not remove that space in your .NET code in the first place?  This is not a job for inline CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your markup has a space, so it will render a space. If you don't want it, don't put it there:

```
<span style="color: Red;white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px">$<%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:F}", item.cy_list_price))%></span>
```

HTML suppresses **extra** whitespace, but preserves one space.